# iOS - Programmatically Set A UIContainerView's Embedded UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIContainerView` inside. Based on whether a certain condition is true, I'd like to programmatically set the container view's embedded view to a different `UIViewController`. I noticed that you can have only one embed segue to set one `UIViewController`, so is there a way to get this done?

I tried setting my container view as an outlet, but I could not find any methods that set an embedded `UIViewController`. Any advice on how to get started with this would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: Don't mix Storyboard and programmatic settings. Do one at a time. 
There is nothing wrong with mixing both but you risk getting confused until you fully understood how the storyboard really works.

Comment: You may want to overwrite `- prepareForSegue:sender:` to manage different segues based on 3rd conditions. Or don't segue but navigate to the new view controller programmatically or invoke a specific segue from the story board with `- performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your idea is wrong if you meant swapping `UIViews` of `UIViewController` (hope I understood your conception).

A `UIViewController` should have 1 designed `UIView` and should manage the values of that view. As you said, you can use `Containers`, however you should add then `UIViewController` with it's view, so there is an instance which manages this view. Your first `UIViewController` should only add/remove that `ChildViewController`.

So I'd advise:

Implement a category on UIViewController and add following methods:

```
- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content {
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)hideContentController:(UIViewController *)content {
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];
    [content removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

Create `AViewController` and `BViewController`. In `AViewController` call (viewDidLoad?):

```
BViewController *bViewController = [[BViewController alloc] init];
[self displayContentController:bViewController];
```

In `BViewController` manage the view of this controller. `AViewController` should only manage when to show BViewController and when to hide it.

If I misunderstood your question please comment it, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: This is actually a pretty clever way of doing it. Other posts mentioned creating a custom container view controller but this one requires the least amount of complexity and thinking time. Thanks! :)

Comment: According to documentation, both `willMove` and `didMove` should be called by both your methods.

Comment: @Rivera From Apple documentation: _"The removeFromParentViewController() method automatically calls the didMove(toParentViewController:) method of the child view controller after it removes the child."_ AND _"When your custom container calls the addChildViewController(_:) method, it automatically calls the willMove(toParentViewController:) method of the view controller to be added as a child before adding it."_. Hope it answers your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Vive's answer:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showContentController(_ controller: UIViewController, containerView: UIView? = nil) {
        controller.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.frame = (containerView ?? self.view).frame
        (containerView ?? self.view).addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.view.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    func hideContentController(_ controller: UIViewController) {
        controller.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        controller.removeFromParentViewController()
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This (duplicated calls for `will`/`didMove`) is not only not required but causes `willMove` and `didMove` to be called twice - what is invalid. See my comment above with quotation from Apple documentation.