# How to open view controllers in a container view without storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to open a view controller over an existing view controller via button click without using storyboards. How do I do this? Here is what I mean:

Let's say we have three view controllers I can scroll between:

"zeroVC", "oneVC", and "twoVC"

When I press a button on "twoVC" I want to now scroll between:

"zeroVC", "oneVC", and "threeVC"

I tried looking all through stack overflow but they all use storyboards.

Comment: What do you mean by “replacing”?

Comment: In android programming you can replace views using fragments. In ios I want to click a button on the screen and open a new different screen over this screen.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475235/ios-programmatically-set-a-uicontainerviews-embedded-uiviewcontroller

Comment: Yes, you can. In the above link it talks about programmatically embedding a container view controller. Using that, you can create a view controller with a scroll view, make a content view within the scroll view, and put three container view controllers in the scroll view with auto layout constraints.

Comment: I tried Rivera's answer from your link and get the error "Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'addSubview' ". thank you for the help Jay, I am new to swift

Comment: I can provide a MWE sample code after work. In the meantime, you can try other solutions and others might help you out.

Comment: That would be incredible! I will keep programming and reading. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume we have four view controllers: `RedViewController`, `GreenViewController`, `BlueViewController`, and the one to contain them all, `ContainerViewController`.

Although you mentioned a scrolling view controller with three children within, we'll make it a two screen setup to keep it simple.
The following approach is scalable, so you would easily adopt it with an arbitrary number of view controllers.

Our `RedViewController` is 7 lines long:

```swift
class RedViewController: UIViewController {
  override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view = view
  }
}
```

Before we move on to `GreenViewController` and `BlueViewController`, we will define `protocol SwapViewControllerDelegate`:

```swift
protocol SwapViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
  func swap()
}
```

`GreenViewController` and `BlueViewController` will have a `delegate` that conforms to this protocol, which will handle the swapping.
We will make `ContainerViewController` conform to this protocol.

Note that `SwapViewControllerDelegate` has the `AnyObject` in its inheritance list to make it a class-only protocol–we can thus make the delegate weak, to avoid memory retain cycle.

The following is `GreenViewController`:

```swift
class GreenViewController: UIViewController {
  weak var delegate: SwapViewControllerDelegate?

  override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .green
    self.view = view
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Swap Me!", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
    button.addTarget(
      self,
      action: #selector(swapButtonWasTouched),
      for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(button)

    // Put button at the center of the view
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  @objc private func swapButtonWasTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.swap()
  }
}
```

It has `weak var delegate: SwapViewControllerDelegate?` which will handle the swap when the button added in `viewDidLoad` is touched, triggering the `swapButtonWasTouched` method.

`BlueViewController` is implemented likewise:

```swift
class BlueViewController: UIViewController {
  weak var delegate: SwapViewControllerDelegate?

  override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.view = view
  }


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Swap Me!", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
    button.addTarget(
      self,
      action: #selector(swapButtonWasTouched),
      for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(button)

    // Put button at the center of the view
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  @objc private func swapButtonWasTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.swap()
  }
}
```

The only difference is the `view`'s `backgroundColor` and the `button`'s `titleColor`.

Finally, we'll take a look at `ContainerViewController`.
`ContainerViewController` has four properties:

```swift
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

  let redVC = RedViewController()
  let greenVC = GreenViewController()
  let blueVC = BlueViewController()

  private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.bounces = false
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    return scrollView
  }()
...
}
```

`scrollView` is the view that will contain child view controllers, `redVC`, `greenVC`, and `blueVC`.
We will use autolayout, so don't forget to mark `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` as `false`.

Now, setup autolayout constraints of the `scrollView`:

```swift
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
...
  private func setupScrollView() {
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    let views = ["scrollView": scrollView]
    [
      NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView]|",
        metrics: nil,
        views: views),
      NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrollView]|",
        metrics: nil,
        views: views),
    ]
      .forEach { NSLayoutConstraint.activate($0) }
  }
...
}
```

I used VFL, but you can manually set autolayou constraints as we did for the button above.
Using autolayout, we don't have to set `contentSize` of the scrollView ourselves.
For more information about using autolayout with `UIScrollView`, see [Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

Now the most important `setupChildViewControllers()`:

```swift
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
...
  private func setupChildViewControllers() {
    [redVC, greenVC, blueVC].forEach { addChild($0) }

    let views = [
      "redVC": redVC.view!,
      "greenVC": greenVC.view!,
      "blueVC": blueVC.view!,
    ]
    views.values.forEach {
      scrollView.addSubview($0)
      $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
      $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    [
      NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|[redVC][greenVC]|",
        options: .alignAllTop,
        metrics: nil,
        views: views),
      NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|[redVC][blueVC]|",
        options: .alignAllTop,
        metrics: nil,
        views: views),
      NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|[redVC(==greenVC,==blueVC)]|",
        metrics: nil,
        views: views),
    ]
      .forEach { NSLayoutConstraint.activate($0) }

    [redVC, greenVC, blueVC].forEach { $0.didMove(toParent: self) }

    greenVC.view.isHidden = true

    greenVC.delegate = self
    blueVC.delegate = self
  }
...
}
```

We first add each of `[redVC, greenVC, blueVC]` as child view controllers of `ContainerViewController`.
Then add the `view`'s of child view controllers to `scrollView`.
Set `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor` of the child view controllers to be `view.widthAnchor` and `view.heightAnchor`, in order to make them fullscreen.
Moreover, this will also work when the screen rotates.

Using `views` dictionary, we use VFL to set autolayout constraints.
We will put `greenVC.view` on the right of `redVC.view`: `H:|[redVC][greenVC]|`, and similarly for the `blueVC.view`: `H:|[redVC][blueVC]|`.
To fix the vertical position of `greenVC.view` and `blueVC.view`, add `.alignAllTop` option to the constraints.
Then apply vertical layout for `redVC.view`, and set the height of the `greenVC.view` and `blueVC.view`: `"V:|[redVC(==greenVC,==blueVC)]|`.
The vertical position is set, as we used `.alignAllTop` while setting the horizontal constraints.

We should call `didMove(toParent:)` methods on the child view controllers after we add then as child view controllers.
(If you are wondering about what `didMove(toParent:)` and `addChild(_:)` methods do, apparently they do very little; see [What does addChildViewController actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192005/what-does-addchildviewcontroller-actually-do) and [didMoveToParentViewController and willMoveToParentViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114179/didmovetoparentviewcontroller-and-willmovetoparentviewcontroller?noredirect=1&lq=1).)

Finally, hide `greenVC.view`, and set `greenVC.delegate` and `blueVC.delegate` to `self`.
Then of course, we need `ContainerViewController` to conform to `SwapViewControllerDelegate`:

```swift
extension ContainerViewController: SwapViewControllerDelegate {
  func swap() {
    greenVC.view.isHidden.toggle()
    blueVC.view.isHidden.toggle()
  }
}
```

That's it!
The entire project is uploaded [here](https://github.com/Zeta611/ScrollContainerViewController).

I recommend reading [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1), which is well-documented by Apple. (It is written in Objective-C, but it is actually straightforward to translate into Swift)

Comment: I will work through your example and read up on visual format language, child view controllers, container view controllers, and the rest of the links. Your time and effort is deeply appreciated, man!

Comment: I got it to work with three children!! You don't know how happy I am. Thank you for teaching me.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped! :)

Comment: Final question: how do I set the starting view controller? When I open the app it opens the left child. Is there a way to open the middle child instead?

Comment: You can set the `contentOffset` property of the `scrollView` in the container view controller.

Comment: You are welcome to upvote the question if it helped!

Comment: Awesome!! and of course! you are the reason it worked out.

Comment: Hey bro I tried this but I think I got the width wrong. Is it what you meant? 
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width*2, y: 0)

Comment: That's probably because you are setting the `contentOffset` before the frame of the `scrollView` got set. Try `UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2` instead of `scrollView.frame.size.width*2`.

Comment: Note that this won't work in Playground, as `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` will get you the width of the screen of your Mac.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, it worked! Thank you Jay!!